# Mysql Average on time column?

Tags: mysql, time, average

SELECT avg( duration ) as average FROM `login`;

The datatype for duration is "time", thus my value is like: 00:00:14, 00:20:23 etc

I execute the query it gives me: 2725.78947368421

What is that? I want in time format, can mysql do the average on time??

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(`login`))) FROM Table1;
```

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (duration TIME NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO `login` (duration) VALUES
('00:00:20'),
('00:01:10'),
('00:20:15'),
('00:06:50');
```

Result:

```
00:07:09
```

Comment: additionally you can divide the results of time_to_sec by 60 to get a number result.

Comment: Sometimes simple things can bring joy in one's life. @Mark Byers. Thanks for this!!! Works absolutely fine. :)

Comment: why mine has result =  00:02:54.6363,
what is 6363 ? how to exclude it?

Comment: I have value
01:00:00 and 22:00:00

And by this query average is coming 11:30:00. Which is wrong.

So it should come 23:30.

Comment: @ApoorvaShah you need to add 86400 seconds to 01:00:00 first