# Min, Max, Average and Count grouped into 15 minute bins

Tags: mysql, sql, median, group-by

I have a MySQL query, provided by another user in another thread, that produces a list of a day's ANPR Journey time results in the following format:

```
Plate   Date        Starttime   Endtime    Journey Time
YF10PXE 2014-06-18  10:00:32    10:03:22    00:02:50
KG55GOA 2014-06-18  10:00:39    10:03:25    00:02:46
N380LGN 2014-06-18  10:00:43    10:03:44    00:03:01
X557EFB 2014-06-18  10:01:05    10:03:31    00:02:26
AJ61AOS 2014-06-18  10:01:32    10:41:09    00:39:37
BG58ASO 2014-06-18  10:01:42    10:06:09    00:04:27
HT56ENL 2014-06-18  10:02:21    10:07:27    00:05:06
X449LGS 2014-06-18  10:02:51    11:51:42    01:48:51
KR07DWW 2014-06-18  10:03:19    11:05:45    01:02:26
NA59FKE 2014-06-18  10:03:35    10:44:17    00:40:42
HV13MXY 2014-06-18  10:03:54    10:52:12    00:48:18
HS03FUW 2014-06-18  10:04:35    10:06:19    00:01:44
HX53FKP 2014-06-18  10:06:09    10:06:47    00:00:38
HK11NJU 2014-06-18  10:07:25    10:08:06    00:00:41
HN12OAV 2014-06-18  10:07:56    10:08:51    00:00:55
MM08AZB 2014-06-18  10:08:10    10:08:53    00:00:43
BW57ENK 2014-06-18  10:08:35    10:09:19    00:00:44
AE55LHR 2014-06-18  10:08:35    10:09:18    00:00:43
RV03HMA 2014-06-18  10:09:13    11:07:45    00:58:32
JPO6JEM 2014-06-18  10:10:48    10:11:25    00:00:37
BV62WMP 2014-06-18  10:11:00    10:11:46    00:00:46
X647HBP 2014-06-18  10:12:01    10:18:06    00:06:05
HV13LSJ 2014-06-18  10:12:18    10:12:54    00:00:36
X553UYC 2014-06-18  10:13:29    10:17:51    00:04:22
Y208WGO 2014-06-18  10:13:56    10:23:03    00:09:07
```

SQL command is below:

```
    SELECT 
    A.plate,
    a.date,
    a.time as 'start time',
    b.time as 'end time',
    timediff(B.time, A.time) as 'Journey time'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        x.plate,
            date(x.timestamp) as 'date',
            time(x.timestamp) as 'time',
            COUNT(*) rank
    FROM
        anpr_1 x
    JOIN anpr_1 y ON y.plate = x.plate
        AND ((date(y.timestamp) < date(x.timestamp))
        OR (date(y.timestamp) = date(x.timestamp)
        AND time(y.timestamp) <= time(x.timestamp)))
    GROUP BY x.plate , date(x.timestamp) , time(x.timestamp)) a
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        x.plate,
            date(x.timestamp) as 'Date',
            time(x.timestamp) as 'time',
            COUNT(*) rank
    FROM
        anpr_2 x
    JOIN anpr_2 y ON y.plate = x.plate
        AND ((date(y.timestamp) < date(x.timestamp))
        OR (date(y.timestamp) = date(x.timestamp)
        AND time(y.timestamp) <= time(x.timestamp)))
    GROUP BY x.plate , date(x.timestamp) , time(x.timestamp)) b ON b.plate = a.plate AND b.rank = a.rank
where
    b.time > a.time
        and a.date = '2014-06-18'
        and b.date = '2014-06-18'
        and timediff(B.time, A.time) <= '03:00:00'
order by a.time;
```

While probably over complicated,This command works nicely for what I need.
However what I am looking to do now is create another query that will aggregate these results into 15 minute time bins, with a median average, min and max Journey time, and a Count. so, for example, the 15 minutes of data shown above would appear as:

```
Timeslot    Median       Min           Max    Count
10:00:00    00:02:50    00:00:36    01:48:51    25
10:15:00    ??:??:??    ??:??:??    ??:??:??    ??
```

I have tried various combinations of `group by` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMPs` and looked at similar problems posted to this site, but I've not yet had much success in what I am trying to achieve. Is there anything that you could suggest to assist?

Comment: Do you really want the second line of your result, not just results for 15 minute intervals where data actually exists?

Comment: The data used as an example is just one chunk of 15 minutes, the whole dataset is actually a whole 24-hour period, I just omitted it from the question to keep it short and to the point. I can provide a whole day of example data if required. There is generally at least one entry of data in each 15 minute time interval.

Comment: No, the sample data should be sufficient. The biggest problem with the query is the median since MySQL does not have a function like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with average journey-time instead of median:

```
 SELECT
      `Date`,
      FLOOR(
      ((60* 60 * HOUR(TIMEDIFF(Starttime, '10:00:00')))
      + (60 * MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(Starttime, '10:00:00')))
      + SECOND(TIMEDIFF(Starttime, '10:00:00')))/(15 * 60)) as intervalNo,
      min(Journey_Time), max(Journey_Time), 
      SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(Journey_Time))) as avgTime, 
      count(*) as Journeys  
 FROM table
 GROUP BY 1,2
```

Be aware that this is based on 10:00:00 each day. Just change that to any other starttime. You can use MySQL ADDTIME() function to calculate an actual time-interval from the intervalNo (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime)).

**EDID**

Found a compact Version with 15-min Timeslots:

```
 SELECT
    `Date`,
    FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Starttime, '10:00:00'))/(15 * 60)) as intervalNo,
    SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Starttime, '10:00:00'))/(15 * 60)) * 15 * 60) 
              as TimeInterval,

    min(Journey_Time), max(Journey_Time),
    SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(Journey_Time))),
    count(*) as Journeys

FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a big leap in the right direction, and mostly does what I'm looking for. I've changed the "10:00:00" to "00:00:00" to give me what seems to be the full day of data, but i'm not quite sure where the `ADDTIME()` should go to give the time intervals. in addition, it may be a formatting/data type error on my part, but the avg calculation is returning quite a few NULL values.

Comment: What datatype is your Journey_Time col? Is it TIME?

Comment: Ok, Updated the avg()-function in my answer. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217139/mysql-average-on-time-column) is why :-)

Comment: Perfect! That's solved everything. thank you very much!